# In Python is it considered bad practice to import something solely to expose it in a more convenient manner?

Tags: import, python, disqus

This probably won't make sense without an example. I'm using [python-disqus](https://github.com/disqus/disqus-python) in my Django app, and I'm wrapping it to better decouple it from the rest of my application.

I have a file, disqus.py, which imports `disqusapi` and defines a number of helper functions. Elsewhere in the application code I can simply add `from mango import disqus`, but in a few places it's necessary to capture exceptions which may be raised when making API calls. This means that I'm forced to do something like:

```
from disqusapi import APIError
from mango import disqus

try:
    disqus.thread.fetch(1)
except APIError, error:
    logger.warn('Disqus API error: %s' % error)
```

If instead I were to import `APIError` at the top of disqus.py, I could instead write:

```
from mango import disqus

try:
    disqus.thread.fetch(1)
except disqus.APIError, error:
    logger.warn('Disqus API error: %s' % error)
```

Pyflakes complains about the unused import, but this seems like a reasonable thing to do. Should I happily ignore Pyflakes here, or am I missing a better option?

To be clear, I don't need to modify `disqusapi.APIError` in any way, so subclassing is unnecessary.

Comment: I guess my question is why arent you handling all these exceptions and that import inside of your custom disqus module?

Comment: Possibly better luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @kniteli That certainly _feels_ like the right approach, but in this case I simply want to log any errors that occur. The application code should dictate how errors are handled, but you're right in saying that the right place to _capture_ Disqus-related exceptions is in disqus.py. I suppose that for complete separation of concerns I'd have the helper functions accept callbacks to be invoked when an exception is caught. This may be the right approach but would make both the application code and the wrapping code a little heavier.

Comment: If you're looking to have complete separation between your application and discqus, you would create an wrapper for disqus that exposes a generic API for dealing with comment systems, and then if you want to swap out for a new comment system later on, you write another wrapper using this same API.

But that's too much work.  This is Python, not J2EE. The API police aren't going to arrest you if you have disqus specific code in your webapp.  Keep using disqus.APIError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Python is it considered bad
>   practice to import something solely to
>   expose it in a more convenient manner?

Short answer: No.

Long answer, if you are writing a wrapper to make your own code simpler and easier for you to understand you can do whatever you like.  If you want to wrap other code, or import modules and subclass them, or import modules, and change their methods.

If you're writing code for other people, you probably want to add comments to explain what you're doing.  If it's just for yourself, it's all good.

Comment: I will often do `import os.path as p` and `j = p.join`, when I can't be bothered to use a proper third-party `Path` object. The list of imports at the top is the first thing someone will read when trying to understand your code; while it isn't a good idea to do `from ... import *` and pollute your namespace (except perhaps for basic modules like `math` and `itertools` and `subprocess` etc.), that is what `from ... import ...` is there for I feel.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly common for an `__init__.py` or a package to be full of apparently "unused" imports. I think that pyflakes idea of unused seems a little simplistic, as it can be plainly seen that this import *is* used - just in another module.

It's annoying if you have to just ignore it. Perhaps there is some sort of pragma for pyflakes to override this behaviour.

Whether or not it's good style really depends on the structure of the application. I think you can make arguments for both sides

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use something and it doesn't collide in your namespace it is not inappropriate to `from x import y` it.

However, you may prefer the second option for self-documentation sake. If someone were reading your code, they may not know which API the error is related to, but pulling it from a namespace avoids any ambiguity.